# Google Cloud Shell ssh with customer container image?

Tags: google-cloud-shell

Is it possible to use `gcloud cloud-shell ssh` with a
[custom Cloud Shell container image](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/customizing-container-image)?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what errors have you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported with the gcloud surface today.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).